# Is there a word for a shared idiolect

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a shared idiolect or a dialect understood by only two people?

Comment: "Code", "secret language"? That's what we called it when I was a kid.

Answer (score 3):

**"[cryptolect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cryptolect)"** or "[**cant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cant_%28language%29)" would fit.

> **cryptolect** *(linguistics)* A secretive language form used by a subculture; an arcane cant.

---

> A **cant** (or **cryptolect**) is the jargon or argot of a group, often implying its use to exclude or mislead people outside the group.

---

And there is "[**argot**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot)" also:

> An **argot** is a secret language used by various groups — e.g. schoolmates, outlaws, colleagues, among many others — to prevent outsiders from understanding their conversations.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you. This probably means there is no specific word for an 'argot/cryptolect/cant' used by exactly two people without any intention toward secrecy?

Comment: @Kinnard Hockenhull: We can consider two people a group also. And it is mentioned that an argot can be between schoolmates. So they can always be applied to two people.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase secret language is commonly used.